# How can I use TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules() in .net core?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I'm writing some codes to deal with time zones, so naturally, I'm already having a bad day.  In particular, I've really be struggling to get the DST adjustment rules for time zones.  According the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/TimeZoneInfo.cs#L330) for `TimeZoneInfo`, there should be an instance method called `.GetAdjustmentRules()`.  It was written early in 2015.

However, this console app doesn't compile targeting .net standard 1.6.

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var tz = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        Console.WriteLine(tz.GetAdjustmentRules());
    }
}
```

> CS1061    'TimeZoneInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetAdjustmentRules' and no extension method 'GetAdjustmentRules' accepting a first argument of type 'TimeZoneInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   timezonecore..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

In fact, when I retrieve a list of methods by reflection, I find that are none called `.GetAdjustmentRules()`.  Interestingly, there *is* a private member called `m_adjustmentRules`, that I might be able to use instead.

But where is `.GetAdjustmentRules()`?  If there's no way to use it, is there another way to get this information?

Comment: DST rules are political decisions, they constantly change.  You need an oracle, a database that contains those rules.  And a company that makes itself responsible for updating all the machines when those rules change.  Works fine in Windows, doesn't work in Unix.  You [have to BYOB](https://chrisjean.com/updating-daylight-saving-time-on-linux/).

Comment: I see a number of people are voting to close this as "opinion based".  I disagree with that point of view.  I'm attempting to call a method that is declared in the source code of an object.  The compiler is rejecting my program.  There's no need to apply any opinion.  My question is how to call the method declared in the source.

Comment: I do agree that this question is more a "technical why" instead of questioning the reasoning. figuring out how compile-time reference, "bait-and-switch" packages and runtime dependency resolution works is different than a "i want this to be in" aspect. maybe, @recursive, you could rephrase the question to highlight this?

Comment: @MartinUllrich:  I changed the title, and added a few words that might clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" is you don't directly reference `mscorlib`, you reference `System.Runtime` that is pulled in by dependencies of `Microsoft.NETCore.App`. The purpose of `System.Runtime` is to abstract away what actually implements all the `System.*` objects. The CoreCLR has implementations in `mscorlib` and the calls are forwarded to it. the CoreRT runtime for example has implementations in `System.Private.CoreLib` (some of which are pure C# implementations that are C++/native method calls in CoreCLR).

So to determine what you can actually call on `TimeZoneInfo`, this is the place to look for 1.0:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/1.0.0/src/System.Runtime/ref/System.Runtime.cs

Both the branches `release/1.0.0` and `release/1.1.0` don't contain a definition of `GetAdjustmentRules()` but the `master` branch does so you can expect that method to be available in .NET Core 1.2.

The method will also be available when just targeting `netstandard2.0` for libraries using `NETStandard.Library`. The reference for what will be available in `netstandard2.0` is currently here:
https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/netstandard/ref

Comment: This answer is not complete. Reflection was attempted, which means the reference assemblies are out the window, and checking the release branch for the implementation shows the method is present. Observe how the reference assemblies contain no private members for classes, but private members exist.

Comment: The reference assemblies are only used for compilation, they contain only stub members to compile themselves. but they provide the reference to the compiler on what methods are available on the actual implementation, which is not used during compilation. (hence, it is the direct reason behind a public method being available to reference during compilation.)

Comment: I guess this evaded your grasp. The implementation in 1.0 seems to be https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/release/1.0.0/src/mscorlib/src/System/TimeZoneInfo.cs and has the method, but reflection still does not find it.

Comment: Yes i am totally aware of there being code for the function, thank you for sharing the direct link. however, it does get included in a way that allows "consumer" code to call it. my answer aims to point out where to look for what is actually available when writing an application for .net core.

Comment: Two failures to address not showing up in reflection, two chances to fix it, not fixed, -1 for you.